# AJAX CORS Request Origin Blocked - Java Web Service

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, cors

Every we tried to access my REST Web Service via AJAX JQuery we've got blocked by Cross-Origin :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://*****
>   (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

We use Java REST Web Service on Glassfish 3.1.2, the client using Firefox Quantum 57.

Please see our code bellow :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: webservice + "/webresources/ivi/syncPassphrase",
    crossOrigin: true,
    data :JSON.stringify({
      'passPhrase' : passphrase
    }),
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data){ 
      syncData = data["output"];  
    }, error: function(){  

    }
});
```

We've read from several answer on SO and have tried like this bellow :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: webservice + "/webresources/ivi/syncPassphrase",
    crossOrigin: true,
    data :JSON.stringify({
      'passPhrase' : passphrase
    }),
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    crossDomain: true,
    timeout: 20000,
    beforeSend: function(xhr){ 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",'http://111.111.111.111:8080');
    },
    success: function(data){ 
      syncData = data["output"];  
      console.log("xxx1 " + syncData);
    }, error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log("xxx2 " + xhr.responseText + " | " + status + " | " + error + " | ");
    }
});
```

But code above still produce same error.

On the server side, we set allow cross origin every request and respond like this code bellow :

```
@Override
public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                  final ContainerResponseContext cres) throws IOException {
  cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
  cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
  cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
}
```

I run out of idea. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Double check that: (1) the filter is actually being applied (by debugging it), (2) the header is not being overwritten in another filter (by debugging through all the filters), (3) response headers are not lost when response is being rewritten by your load balancer (if using any)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. You don't need to sent a ACAO header in your request - this bit of client-side code does nothing:

   ```
   beforeSend: function(xhr){
       xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",'http://111.111.111.111:8080');
   },
   ```
2. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` (ACAO) response header is incompatible with the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` (ACAC) header. If you need cookies or Authentication, you'll have to specify `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {value-of-Origin-request-header}`

That second one might solve it.

**UPDATE**

Your server code should be like this:

```
@Override
public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
              final ContainerResponseContext cres) throws IOException {
  cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://your-origin:port");
  cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
  cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
  cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
}
```

but replace `http://your-origin:port` with the domain of your page which is making the request (including port if it's not 80). I don't know your server code, but if you can retrieve the value of the Origin request header, rather than hard-code it, so much the better.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: From second one, Where i must specify Access Control Allow Origin? at the client or server side? can you provide me more detail with some example maybe?

Comment: You add the ACAO header at the server. Actually your existing server code looks good - just change the value of the ACAO header from an asterisk to the value of the incoming Origin request header. Leave the ACA header as-is. Some of those headers aren't needed in the response to a GET or POST (they're only needed for a preflight OPTIONS request), but they won't break anything if you leave them there.

Comment: you mentioned about `ACAO header from an asterisk to the value of the incoming Origin request header.`, actually incoming origin request header comes from client and use many IP Address. How about this?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the Origin header is (perhaps it's `https://www.example.com` or perhaps it's `https://127.0.0.1:8080` or whatever) - just mirror it back in the ACAO response header. If there is no Origin request header, then you don't need CORS anyway.

Comment: Obviously, I don't get it. Can you provide an example for me?